# Are there guides for Router Contracts available (now or in the near future)?

Tags: plutus

Will IOHK be publishing best practice guides or common architectures?  For example, in solidity it's common to have a set of "Router" contracts, to assist in upgrading the protocol in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as Plutus is brand new and that our Pioneers are the very first people who every write Plutus contracts, there are no best practices yet - and we hope our pioneers will help us discover and document some.

Of course, as soon as people have gathered experience with Plutus, we will be happy to publish such best practices.